# How to send shipment e-mail by order id

Tags: magento2, order-email, shipment

Is there a way to send an order shipment email with only order id provided?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague question but everything you need for this is in

```
Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender
```

If you have the order id you can use the below interface to load the order

```
Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::get($id)
```

You can then get all of your shipments using `$order->getShipmentsCollection()` and loop through

Provided the shipment sender is included in your constructor you can then just do

```
$this->shipmentSender->send($shipment);
```

Alternatively you can always use `Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentRepositoryInterface::getList()` with search criteria to load all shipments filtering by your order id. Or even just use the collection factory to load all shipments filtering by the order id. Either way you need an instance of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment` in order to make use of the `ShipmentSender`

Comment: Was this not helpful ?